# How to set a user in first time fixture load in Symfony?

Tags: php, symfony, security

In my Symfony project there is a `User` entity which I used as a user provider. It has these fields:

```
User
- id (PK)
- name
- email
- created_by
```

The `created_by` field (which contains a reference to who created this user) will be automatically set by blameable-behaviour. When deploying the project there are no users in the system. I want to persist users by fixture load. It currently fails because at the time I run them there are no users. 
Is there any solution in Symfony for this??

Please don't suggest inserting users directly into the database or use another table and rename like answers. I'm looking for an elegant solution to this.

Comment: Have you added fixtures file in your Bundle and tried to load the fixtures via command?

Comment: yes. before adding blemeable extension all are work fine. Now only problem is FIRST USER.

Comment: There was a solution. Override blemeable extension. now i'm trying that.
Here there is another problem. The class path is wrong. I cannot find the correct way to do this

Comment: I can assume that fails, because you defined `createdBy` field to be mandatory. Just explicitly set it within your fixtures to something like "system" or mark field nullable in schema.

Comment: no dear that also didn't work

Comment: It's ok friends. There is no solution for that other than changing the architecture. Problem is there. If foreign key is stored there is no solution. If foreign key is didn't store, that is not professional work. So i changed the property to null in the startup. Thank you all for helping.thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you need to load an initial user into the database with fixtures.

I use this code:

```php
// src/AppBundle/DataFxitures/ORM/LoadUserData.php
<?php
namespace AppBundle\DataFixtures\ORM;

use Doctrine\Common\DataFixtures\FixtureInterface;
use Doctrine\Common\Persistence\ObjectManager;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerAwareInterface;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInterface;
use AppBundle\Entity\User;

class LoadUserData implements FixtureInterface, ContainerAwareInterface
{
    /**
     * @var ContainerInterface
     */
    private $container;

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    public function setContainer(ContainerInterface $container = null)
    {
        $this->container = $container;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    public function load(ObjectManager $manager)
    {
        $userAdmin = new User();
        $userAdmin->setUsername('admin');
        $userAdmin->setTrueName('Admin');

        $userAdmin->setEmail('admin@admin.lan');
        $userAdmin->setEnabled(true);
        $hash = $this->container->get('security.password_encoder')->encodePassword($userAdmin, 'admin');
        $userAdmin->setPassword($hash);
        $manager->persist($userAdmin);
        $manager->flush();
    }
}
```

But, you can also just load it via command that the FOSUserBundle exposes:

```php
php app/console fos:user:create
```

Comment: problem is loading the first fixture.

Comment: Can you please post the *exact* error message you're getting when inserting fixtures into the DB.

Comment: [Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException]  
  Error: Call to a member function getUser() on null

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should use OrderedFixtureInterface.
This will allow you to choose the order of loaded fixture.

```
use Doctrine\Common\DataFixtures\OrderedFixtureInterface;

class LoadUser extends AbstractFixture implements OrderedFixtureInterface
        {

        public function load(ObjectManager $manager)
        {
            $user1 = new User();
            $user1->setUsername('...');
            $user1->setPlainPassword('...');
            $user1->setEmail('...');
            $user1->setRoles(array('ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN'));
            $user1->setEnabled(true);
            $this->addReference($user1->getUsername(), $user1); 
            $manager->persist($user1);
            $manager->flush();
        }

            public function getOrder() {
                return 1;
            }
        }
```

And then in another fixture class

class LoadPost extends AbstractFixture implements OrderedFixtureInterface {

```
    public function load( ObjectManager $manager ) {

  [...] fixture

        foreach ( $posts as $post ) {
            ...
            $p->setAuthor( $this->getReference( ... ));

    }

    public function getOrder() {
        return 12; //or whatever after your order in LoadUser
    }
```